# Google Maps not working in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm trying to add Google Map in my Rails app with

> Rails 5.1.6 and Ruby 2.5.0 using the gem "gmaps4rails"

But I'm only seeing this BLUE color on the map.

[image: Map Image]

I followed all the step mention at the documentation gem 'gmaps4rails',
[here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails)

**Index Page**

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus/master/dist/markerclusterer.min.js"></script>
<script src='//cdn.rawgit.com/printercu/google-maps-utility-library-v3-read-only/master/infobox/src/infobox_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <center><h3>Bus Detail</h3></center>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div style='width: 100%;'>
      <div id="map" style='width: 100%; height: 400px;'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function() 
   {
    markers = handler.addMarkers([
      { 
        "lat": 0,
        "lng": 0,
        "picture": {
          "url": "http://icon- park.com/imagefiles/location_map_pin_yellow5.png",
          "width":  32,
          "height": 32
        },
        "infowindow": "hello!"
      }
    ]);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
  });
</script>
```

**Application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require gmaps/google
//= require underscore
//= require_tree .
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I have gone through the documentation 3 times but didn't found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad.

I have to assign Lat and Lan in Gmaps.build function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers([
      {
        "lat": 31.5204,
        "lng": 74.3587,
        "picture": {
          "url": "http://icon-park.com/imagefiles/location_map_pin_yellow5.png",
          "width":  32,
          "height": 32
        },
        "infowindow": "hello!"
      }
    ]);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
  });
</script>
```